# FIFO Balance at every month end with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the balance quantity at the end of every month i.e. running total at every month end with FIFO only but its not showing any result. Pls help
Here is my query.

```
declare @Stock table (Item char(3) not null,Date date not null,TxnType varchar(3) not null,Qty int not null,Price decimal(10,2) null)
insert into @Stock(Item ,  [Date] ,        TxnType, Qty,  Price) values
('ABC','20120401','IN',    200, 750.00),
('ABC','20120402','OUT',   100 ,null  ),
('ABC','20120403','IN',     50, 700.00),
('ABC','20120404','IN',     75, 800.00),
('ABC','20120405','OUT',   175, null  ),
('XYZ','20120406','IN',    150, 350.00),
('XYZ','20120407','OUT',   120 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120408','OUT',    10 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120409','IN',     90, 340.00),
('ABC','20120510','IN',    200, 750.00),
('ABC','20120511','OUT',   100 ,null  ),
('ABC','20120512','IN',     50, 700.00),
('ABC','20120513','IN',     75, 800.00),
('ABC','20120514','OUT',   175, null  ),
('XYZ','20120515','IN',    150, 350.00),
('XYZ','20120516','OUT',   120 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120517','OUT',    10 ,null  ),
('XYZ','20120518','IN',     90, 340.00);

;WITH OrderedIn as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month(date) ORDER BY DATE) as rn
    from @Stock
    where TxnType = 'IN'
), RunningTotals as (
    select Item,Qty,Price,Qty as Total,0 as PrevTotal,rn from OrderedIn where rn = 1
    union all
    select rt.Item,oi.Qty,oi.Price,rt.Total + oi.Qty,rt.Total,oi.rn
    from
        RunningTotals rt
            inner join
        OrderedIn oi
            on
                rt.Item = oi.Item and
                rt.rn = oi.rn - 1
), TotalOut as (
    select Item,SUM(Qty) as Qty from @Stock where TxnType='OUT' group by Item
)
select
    rt.Item,SUM(CASE WHEN PrevTotal > out.Qty THEN rt.Qty ELSE rt.Total - out.Qty END * Price)
from
    RunningTotals rt
        inner join
    TotalOut out
        on
            rt.Item = out.Item
where
    rt.Total > out.Qty
group by rt.Item
```

Output

```
Month     Item   (No column name(qty*price))
4      ABC        40000
4      XYZ        37600
5      ABC        77500
5      XYZ        76100
```

Comment: For those of us who can do SQL but have no idea what you're talking about, what would a successful result look like?

Comment: Output
Month   Item   (No column name(qty*price))
4           ABC    40000
4           XYZ    37600
5           ABC    77500
5           XYZ    76100

Comment: @manishsingh - can you add the desired output in question

Comment: I have written output in my comment above. I am not able to edit the question its throwing some error

Comment: @NoDisplayName... Pls solve this

Comment: @Derek Tomes... Pls solve this

Comment: @NoDisplayName I have added output in the question.

Comment: @manishsingh - I tried to figure out how `(No column name(qty*price))` is calculated but didn't get anything so can you explain in simple terms how it is calculated. take this row as example `4      ABC        40000`.

Comment: @NoDisplayName In this case of 4 ABC 40000. First we will do calculation of ABC for the 4th month only after which we will get 50 as balance quantity. And since its FIFO based so after the calculation you will see that this 50 will be left in the 4th row of input which is having price of 800. So quantity*price i.e. 50*800=40000. If still you are not clear then please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @NoDisplayName You have all the tym.

Answer (score 0):

With you sample data.Are you looking for this,else clearly sketch your desired output .

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
select Item ,[Date] ,TxnType ,s.Qty
,Price ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month(date),TxnType ORDER BY DATE) as rn
from @Stock S 
)
,
 CTE1 AS
(
SELECT ITEM ,[DATE] ,TXNTYPE ,QTY,MONTH(DATE) MONTHDT,RN FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
UNION ALL
SELECT S.ITEM ,S.[DATE] ,S.TXNTYPE ,S.QTY+A.QTY,A.MONTHDT ,S.RN
FROM CTE S INNER JOIN  CTE1 A 
ON S.TXNTYPE=A.TXNTYPE AND MONTH(S.[DATE])=A.MONTHDT AND S.RN-A.RN=1


)
,CTE2 AS
(
SELECT  *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month(date),TxnType  ORDER BY QTY DESC )RN1 
FROM CTE1 S 
)

SELECT A.DATE,A.QTY-(SELECT B.Qty from CTE2 B 
where a.MONTHDT=b.MONTHDT and b.RN1=1 AND b.TxnType='OUT')
from CTE2 A
WHERE A.RN1=1 AND a.TxnType='IN'
```

Comment: Its not giving the desired output. I have added output in the question itself. Pls follow that

Comment: @kumarharsha sorry harsha I dont know how to format this. Pls do it and help me in writing this query.

Comment: you hv not explain,price is null where TxnType='OUT' why,then what will be price in that case .

Comment: since its FIFO based so the item IN first that will be OUT first. So no matter of price is there. But if you want then you can take anything as price. We have to calculate only for quantity left whose price is given there. Please let me know if want any other clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY item, Datepart(mm, date) ORDER BY date DESC) rn,
                item,
                Month(date)             AS [month],
                TxnType,
                Price,
                date
         FROM   #Stock
         WHERE  TxnType = 'IN'),
     cte1
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY item, Datepart(mm, date) ORDER BY date DESC)       rn,
                item,
                Month(date)                   [month],
                (SELECT Sum(CASE
                              WHEN TxnType = 'out' THEN -1 * qty
                              ELSE qty
                            END) AS qty
                 FROM   #Stock b
                 WHERE  a.item = b.item
                        AND a.Date >= b.Date) qty
         FROM   #Stock a)
SELECT a.[month],
       a.Item,
       ( a.Price * b.qty ) running_tot
FROM   cte a
       JOIN cte1 b
         ON a.Item = b.Item
            AND a.[month] = b.[month]
WHERE  a.rn = 1
       AND b.rn = 1
```

Comment: FIFO is not working here because according to FIFO in case of 4 XYZ,  90 quantity should be left with 340 price and 20 with 350 price and then the answer will be 37600. And same should happen in all the outputs. Quantity left will be with different prices in these situations. Follow FIFO only.

Comment: How you got that `90` quantity

Comment: Total quantity left we will get as 110. But according to FIFO the sold quantity will be deducted from the begining only in sequence. And in that sequence we will have left quantity 20 with 350 price and then 90 with 340 price. Total quantity left is correct in all the cases.

Comment: @manishsingh - sorry am not clear. can you explain these two rows `4      ABC        40000 &  5      ABC        77500` with manual calculation if possible

Comment: For 4 ABC. In the starting bought 200 with 750 price. Then sold 100. Now only 100 left with 750 price. Now again bought 50 with 700. So total will be 150 (100 with 750 price and 50 with 700). Now again bought 75 with price of 800. Now total will be 225 (100 with 750 price, 50 with 700 price and 75 with 800 price). Now here sold 175. For this first 100 will be deducted from left 100 at very starting (because only 100 is available), next 50 will be deducted from next 50 (because only 50 is available) and last 25 will be deducted from last 75. At the end we will have only 50 qty with 800 price.

Comment: Same will happen for 5 ABC also. In this case again the calculation will start in the same way and at the end we will have only 100 quantities left (75 with 800 price and 25 with 700 price) and so the price will be 77500 (qty*price). For this either you can start calculation from very starting or from last month's left quantity and price. But result should be correct

Comment: Pls do it and if you need any other clarification then let me know.